# Force Windows Batch Script Return Code 0

Tags: windows, batch-file

A vendor has provided us with a Windows Batch script that needs to have a return code of 0.

Per that vendor, there are safe to ignore messages being printed by the script.

The scripts are used for quiescing the application for a proper backup. Our backup software requires a return code of 0.

How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to do "yourscript.cmd && someothercommand.exe" or ERRORLEVEL checking in a "parent" batch script?

Comment: I am only interested in postscript.bat executing with a return code of 0

Comment: Well, there is batch return code and process return code and they are not exactly the same.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

End the script with:

```
exit /b 0
```

Answer (score 6):

adding a line to the end of the script

```
Ver > nul
```

should do the trick

Comment: Does it need to be "scriptname.bat Ver > nul" ?

Comment: @andyh_ky: Andy said "adding _to the end of the script_". So no, you have to add it to _the script itself_.